# get string by regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to match following strings:

```
input               --->  output
------------------------------
1*a12*asd*315       ---> a12
113-a12-asd*315     ---> a12
+1-a12-asd-315      ---> a12
as3-a12-asd*315     ---> a12
as3-a12-a           ---> a12
a-a12-a             ---> a12
a-a12-aas           ---> a12
-a12-aas-asd        ---> a12
*a12*aas*asd        ---> a12
a*a12*aas*sd        ---> a12
```

Hope examples are enough. What I tried is:

```
(^(?=.{1,3}$)-([a-zA-Z])-(?=.*)$)
```

but not working? What will be the correct regex for this?

---

for examples I have used `a12`. It can be anything. I don't know what the string will be, need to extract that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an expression like:

```
([*-])([a-zA-Z\d]+)\1
```

The desired value will be in the second capturing group after successful match.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex you can use

```
input.contains("a12");
```

to know whether it has that string or not.

Or otherwise if you want the string then you can use

```
input.copyValueOf({'a','1','2'});
```

Comment: for examples I have used `a12`. It can be anything.

Comment: @mark pass that string value inside the corresponding method.

Comment: I don't know what the string will be.

Comment: @mark If you don't know the string value, then how would you search it from input even using the regex?

Comment: Actually first I need to match the string with regex and then extract that part.